# SWF Files appear much smaller in chrome than other web browsers

Tags: html

So no matter, if i change the width and height dimensions, it doesnt change, and appears much smaller in Google Chrome, than any other browser.

Here is the code im using:

```
<div style="text-align: center;"><object>
  <param name="movie" value="Portfolio/files/book.swf" />
  <param name="quality" value="high" />
  <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
  <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
  <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
  <embed src="Portfolio/files/book.swf" 
     quality="high" 
     name="fb" 
     allowScriptAccess="always" 
     allowFullScreen="true" 
     wmode="window"
     pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" 
     type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
     width="900" 
     height="500">
   </embed>
</object></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your width and height within your `<object>` tag.